# How do I move from one list item to another in android?

Tags: java, android

I'm currently developing an app that has a view pager with tabs. Each tab has a list of titles. Tab1 has Lessons, say Lesson1, Lesson2, Lesson3. Tab2 has Questions for each lesson. When a user clicks on Lesson1 (in Lessons tab), the details of that lesson are shown. I want that, when a user is currently viewing the details of Lesson1, they can swip right to Lesson2 details and vice-versa, without having to go back to the list. Sorry it may be a dumb question but I'm stuck. Please help!

Here is the list fragment that takes the list of Lessons titles from the Lessons class:

```
public class LessonsListFragment extends ListFragment {

    //add the listener to the list fragment
    static interface Listener {
        void itemClicked(long id);
    }

    private Listener listener;

    //the list fragment
    public LessonsListFragment() {
        //requires empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //the string array
        String[] lessonTitles = new String[Lessons.lessons.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < lessonTitles.length; i++) {
            lessonTitles[i] = Lessons.lessons[i].getTitle(); //create array of titles
        }
        // Attach data to the list view
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(
                inflater.getContext(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, lessonTitles
                /*getResources().getStringArray(R.array.masomo)*/
        );
        setListAdapter(adapter);
        return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    }


    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        this.listener = (Listener) context; //attach the listener to the activity when it gets attached to activity
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        if (listener != null) {
            listener.itemClicked(id);

        }
    }
}
```

And here is the lessons details fragment layout, that displays the details after the title is clicked in the ListView of Lesson Titles

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".LessonsDetailsFragment">

    <!-- Getting the layouts -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="16dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lesson_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAlignment="gravity"
            android:textIsSelectable="true"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lesson_description"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textIsSelectable="true"
            android:textAlignment="gravity"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lesson_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAlignment="gravity"
            android:textIsSelectable="true"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.SearchResult.Subtitle" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/maswali_sehemu_ya_"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:paddingTop="10dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

What I want is that, the user sees a list of titles, clicks a title (say Lesson 2) then details for lesson2 are displayed. Now, the user should be able to swipe left-to-right to go back to lesson 1 or right-to-left to go back to the next lesson, lesson3, without having to go back again to the list of titles. I appreciate it for any help from you guys. Please help, I'm stuck.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Hello, it would be much helpful, if you provide us some code. :)

Comment: Check code above @L.Papadopoulos, see how you can help. Thanks

Comment: Pls see code @nylanderdev, you can do this. Tnx.